# Understanding a Julia statement comprising == && increment and continue

Tags: julia, continue

I am trying to translate some Julia routine into C (C#, C++). I fail to understand the particular line

```
n == n0 && (n+=1; continue)
```

in the following loop.

```
ret1, ret2, n = 1, 0, 0
while n < m
    n == n0 && (n+=1; continue)
    ret1 *= z+n
    ret2 += 1/(z+n)
    n += 1
end
```

How is the increment function before exiting the loop.

Comment: Not a Julia expert, but looks like it wants to skip the iteration where `n==n0`. `&&` is short-circuit evaluating just as in C, so the right-hand side of it will be only evaluated if the left-hand is true. In that case it will increment `n` and skip to the next iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code, `(n+=1; continue)` is a compound expression, similar to using a block. The `&&` has short-circuit evaluation semantics, where the right-hand-side is only evaluated if the left-hand-side is true. It would be much clearer and better style, imo, to write this code like this:

```
ret1, ret2, n = 1, 0, 0
while n < m
    if n == n0
        n += 1
        continue
    end
    ret1 *= z+n
    ret2 += 1/(z+n)
    n += 1
end
```

Better still, would be to invert the condition and only evaulate the body statements if on the later iterations:

```
ret1, ret2, n = 1, 0, 0
while n < m
    if n != n0
        ret1 *= z+n
        ret2 += 1/(z+n)
    end
    n += 1
end
```

Comment: Continuing with the refactoring theme, this should actually be a `for` loop: `ret1, ret2 = 1.0, 0.0; for n in 0:m-1 ; n == n0 && continue ; ret1 *= z+n; ret2 += 1/(z+n); end`

Comment: ...and another refactor: `ret1 = prod(z+n for n in 0:m-1 if n != n0); ret2 = sum(1/(z+n) for n in 0:m-1 if n != n0)`